# Azure DevOps back log doesn't show completed epics

Tags: azure-devops

Azure DevOps back log doesn't show completed epics

Am wondering how to create a backlog query of my own that shows "everything" .. i.e. All Epics ..

Microsoft mentioned this but unfortunately their support article image link to show how to query this is no longer present.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/320703/epics-in-done-state-no-long-visible-in-backlog-vie.html

I'm also interested in the "drill down" ability as per the Dashboard .. Epics to Features, to User Stories to tasks and bugs .. Seems a query result doesn't have this easy drill down as per the dashboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The completed Epics work item are still showing in Boards.

You can create query to show all the Epics. See below:

Navigate to Queries-->New Query-->Set the query condtion like below.

[image]

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops) for more information.

After the query is created. You can then add the query result to Dashboard. See below screenshot.

[image]

Update:

Check below screenshot to change the permission to contribute the shared group.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Levi ! ..I don't have the "Add to dashboard" option here ..  maybe security. maybe I'm locked down a bit ..  The results doesn't have the "drill down" ability of the usual dashboard so am interested in having all Epics on dashboard !

Comment: I can use the "related work" section bottom right to drill down to other levels and items .. Guess this is good enough ..  Have to note that this "related work" can be spread over multiple pages and have to navigate to other pages.

Comment: Maybe the query has to be saved to "Shared Queries" folder / area before the "Add to dashboard" option is offered ? I don't have access to save to "Shared Queries". I get message : TF401256: You do not have Write permissions for query Shared Queries.

Comment: @AllanF You can ask  your project administrator or anyone who has the permission to grant you the permission to contribute to shared queries. See above update:

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure that in the epic view, the "Completed child items" is ON
   [image]
2. make sure that epics have at least one child (a feature or user story). That is the reason why the closed Epics were not showing up for me
   [image]